# Application Freeze Android using parse Frame work small data loading

Tags: android, performance, parse-platform

I am using Parse Frame Work 1.14.1 in android. i am loading data around 25 from query while execute it's query my Application Gui is fully stuck or freeze. And Arise ANR of Dialog  How to resolve it any solution for that ?

Here my code is :

```
    progressLayout.showLoading();

    mapForProfiel.clear();

    final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Posts");
    query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(final List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

            hideProgressDialog();

            progressLayout.showContent();

            if (e == null) {

                for (ParseObject parseObject : objects) {


                    CanvasPostModel profilePostModel = new CanvasPostModel();
                    profilePostModel.setObjectId(parseObject.getObjectId());

                    profilePostModel.setUpdateAt(parseObject.getUpdatedAt() + "");


                    profilePostModel.setPostOwnerObject(((ParseUser) parseObject.get("postOwner")).getObjectId() + "");


                    AppUtility.showLog("--- post obj owner " + ((ParseUser) parseObject.get("postOwner")).getObjectId());

                    try {
                        profilePostModel.setPostOwner(((ParseUser) parseObject.get("postOwner")).fetchIfNeeded().getString("fullName"));
                        AppUtility.showLog("--- post user owner " + ((ParseUser) parseObject.get("postOwner")).fetchIfNeeded().getString("fullName"));
                    } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (((ParseFile) parseObject.get("postThumb")) != null) {

                        profilePostModel.setPostThumb(((ParseFile) parseObject.get("postThumb")).getUrl());
                    }
                    profilePostModel.setCreatedAt(parseObject.getCreatedAt() + "");

                    profilePostModel.setNoOfDays(AppUtility.getDaysDiffrent(AppUtility.formatedDate(parseObject.getCreatedAt() + "")) + "");


                    if (((ParseFile) parseObject.get("postFile")) != null) {
                        profilePostModel.setPostFile(((ParseFile) parseObject.get("postFile")).getUrl());

                    }
                    profilePostModel.setPostDescription(parseObject.getString("postDescription"));
                    profilePostModel.setAtttachmentLink(parseObject.getString("attachmentLink"));

                    if (parseObject.getJSONArray("likedBy") == null) {
                        profilePostModel.setNoOfFavoriteCount("0");
                    } else {
                        profilePostModel.setLikedby(parseObject.getJSONArray("likedBy").toString());
                        profilePostModel.setNoOfFavoriteCount(parseObject.getJSONArray("likedBy").length() + "");
                        JSONArray jArry = (parseObject.getJSONArray("likedBy"));


                        for (int i = 0; i < jArry.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jobj = jArry.getJSONObject(i);
                                if (jobj.optString("objectId").equalsIgnoreCase(currentUser.getObjectId())) {
                                    profilePostModel.setSelfLiked(true);
                                    break;
                                } else {
                                    profilePostModel.setSelfLiked(false);
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    mapForProfiel.put(parseObject.getObjectId(), profilePostModel);
                    profilePostModelArrayList.add(profilePostModel);


                    //setPostListWithMap();
                    ParseQuery<ParseUser> parseObjectParseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
                    parseObjectParseQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId", profilePostModel.getPostOwnerObject());

                    try {
                        //   List<ParseUser> parseObjects = parseObjectParseQuery.find();


                        // AppUtility.showLog("---- parse object " + parseObjects);


                        ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQueryForFriend = ParseQuery.getQuery("Friendships");
                        parseQueryForFriend.whereEqualTo("fromUser", currentUser);
                        parseQueryForFriend.whereEqualTo("toUser", ((ParseUser) parseObject.get("postOwner")));
                        parseQueryForFriend.setLimit(1);

                        List<ParseObject> parseObjectsFriend = parseQueryForFriend.find();

                        if (parseObjectsFriend.size() > 0) {
                            AppUtility.showLog("---- parse friend object" + parseObjectsFriend.get(0));

                            if (parseObjectsFriend.get(0).getBoolean("requestAccepted")) {

                                profilePostModelArrayListTemp.add(profilePostModel);

                            }
                        }


                    } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }





            } else {
                Toast.makeText(CanvasActivity.this, "Error: " + e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: you should not load any data on the main thread.

Comment: there is some problem in your code.

Comment: @szholdiyarov i am loading data in background thread not in main thread

Comment: @MehulTank please share the code so that we can see what is wrong

Comment: @MehulTan Please try to handle the response List<ParseObject> objects in some background task

Comment: Is their any join method in parse frame work???

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you consider using AsyncTask to download data:

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;


             // your download things

         return count;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

refer to [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: the OP stated in comments that he already doing the load in the background

Comment: My only guess that he is handling and processing data in the MainThread

Comment: 'i am loading data in background thread not in main thread – Mehul Tank"